# ADX Optimized Autoscale quick to scale up than scale down?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Based on my observation an ADX cluster with 'Optimized Autoscale' quickly scales up steeply (within matter of 1 or 2 hours) if cluster load increases (based on metrics such as cache utilization, ingestion utilization, cpu etc. But when this load goes down to normal, the cluster is very very slow at scaling down and in fact even when it does , it doesn't go back to old number of nodes even after a day or two. That has an impact on the cost. So it seems like somehow ADX has a bias towards high number of nodes in that it probably places much stricter criteria for scale down than for scale up. It's not very transparent. Does someone have a clue on this? I have noticed that a cluster quickly increased from 60s to 80s based on geuine load but even when all the metrics went back to the state when it was running in 60s , the cluster kept lingering around 79 nodes for couple of days impacting cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Data Explorer Optimized autoscale tracks critical usage metrics to make sure there are sufficient resources to perform all required operations, like query execution and data ingestion.
The logic for scaling out or scaling in a cluster is very similar and contains different thresholds to prevent a state where a cluster scales out and in constantly.
You're correct that we're more conservative when making a decision to scale the cluster in to make sure performance and usage are not impacted; therefore we would required more time to analyze the cluster metrics and decide if we can make it smaller (6 hour time interval vs. 1 hour time interval in the case of scale out).
Once the higher load goes down and returns to the previous state the cluster should return to its original size.
You can also modify the cluster size manually if you would like to reduce the cost and after that enable Optimized autoscale to view if it increases the cluster.
In case, you still believe the cluster is not scaling properly please open a support ticket.

Comment: thanks, very insightful, so can we say that even before reducing even a single node it will monitor the key metrics at least for 6 hours?